# DateTimeImmutable method type is not visible in runtime

Tags: php, datetime, php-7

I've extended DateTimeImmutable with my custom class:

```
class NullDateTime extends DateTimeImmutable
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(DateTimeUtil::NULL_DATETIME);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function add(DateInterval $interval) {}
```

And I get error `NullDateTime::add(DateInterval $interval) should be compatible with DateTimeImmutable::add($interval)`
As you can see php doesn't expect the DateInterval type for some reason, even though it is defined in DateTimeImmutable (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php).

If I remove the type from my class like this

```
public function add($interval) {}
```

Then it starts to work.

**Why the type isn't recognized as part of a contract during runtime**? (It seems all the methods from DateTimeImmutable acts the same).

Comment: Return type is missing: `public function add(DateInterval $interval): DateTimeImmutable`. But this works without any error on PHP 8. It looks like a PHP 7 error. https://3v4l.org/9F9OY